# Toolbar overflow menu items not highlighed properly

Tags: android, menu, overflow, toolbar, android-appcompat

I have a problem that frustrates me a lot. I can't get to the end of it. The menu items in the overflow menu in the Toolbar of my Android app are not highlighted properly. That is, only the background outside of the text changes color when the button is pressed, while the background behind the text does not. Here's a screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1UL0.jpg
I've found questions with this exact problem, but with no answers. Please help me.
Regards,
Aleksandar

UPDATE
Here's the source for my styles and the Toolbar:

```
<style name="BaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/converterColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/converterColorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/converterColorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/converterWindowBackground</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/converterWindowTextColor</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/converterControlColorNormal</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/converterColorControlHighlight</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="BaseTheme"/>

<style name="ToolbarThemeOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/converterColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/converterToolbarTextColorPrimary</item>
</style>

<style name="ToolbarPopupTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:background">@color/converterWindowBackground</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/converterWindowTextColor</item>
</style>

<style name="ToolbarTitleTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/converterToolbarTextColorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>
```

Toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                               xmlns:converter="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:id="@+id/app_bar"
converter:theme="@style/ToolbarThemeOverlay"
converter:popupTheme="@style/ToolbarPopupTheme"
converter:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarTitleTextAppearance"/>
```

Comment: Unless you post your code, no one can't help you.

Comment: @YuvaRaj I added the sources for the styles and toolbar.

Comment: Remove this line `<item name="android:background">@color/converterWindowBackground</item>` and try. I'm not sure but give a try. What's the color code of `converterWindowBackground`?

Comment: When I remove that line, the background color is inherited from the toolbar color, and the problem still exists. The color code of converterWindowBackground is #f5f5f5 @YuvaRaj